# "Windows Search Service" query results do not show thumbnails but icons

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, search-engine

I am having a strange issue here on several Windows Server 2012 R2 machines.

**Problem description:**

Client machines searching a mapped network drive get the results shown as icons instead of thumbnails. The search results (like *.doc, *.txt) can not be opened via double-click. Sometimes there are no icons at all, but only lines seperating the "hidden" search results.

[image]

[image]

**Intermediate workaround**

Restarting the Windows Search Search Service temporarily "fixes" this issue.

**Additional Notes:**

1.) This is the only event entry that shows a warning related to Windows Search Service

```
Crawl could not be completed on content source <winrt://{S-1-5-xx-18xx460xx2-12xxx74957-4xx62xx635-xxxxxxx}/>.

Context:  Application, SystemIndex Catalog

Details:
    The parameter is incorrect.  (HRESULT : 0x80070057) (0x80070057)
```

2.) Client machines are running Windows 7 and Windows Vista

3.) The box `Always show icons, never thumbnails` is unchecked within the folder options on the server (though not relevant to the client)

4.) Within `Performance Options` on the server the box `Show thumbnails instead of icons` is checked (though not relevant to the client)

5.) Searching on **local** client drives correctly displays thumbnails

Comment: Try to check if `windows search service` don't crash in eventlog . Sometime its corrupted database or indexing composant broken . Another trick could be to put in autorestard this service but its dirty :)

Comment: Thx for replying. Unfortunately there is nothing related to a service/application crash within the logs. Restarting the service regularily is no option.